# UITextView Word Wrapping Unexpected behavior

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a UITextView with Content and frame size widths equal to 348, but word wrapping happens whenever text width on a line exceeds 338.61. Does anyone know why this might be happening? How can I access the width that the UITextView uses for word wrapping dynamically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of iOS 7, yes. It's a combination of `textContainerInset` and `lineFragmentPadding`.

```
UITextView *textView = ...;
CGFloat wrappingWidth = textView.bounds.size.width - (textView.textContainerInset.left + textView.textContainerInset.right + 2 * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding);
```

Which is a nice value to know about. You can use it in `boundingRectWithSize:` calls, for example:

```
CGRect boundingRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(wrappingWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin // this is important
                                      attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: textView.font } // and any other attributes of your text
                                         context:nil];
```

Also cool is the fact that you can set `textContainerInset` and `lineFragmentPadding`, so if you want to increase this or have a `UITextView` that renders with no insets (so it matches a `UILabel`, for example), you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped. I wasn't able to find this anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the answer above but I have been researching the UITextView word wrapping behavior and have discovered that although one can adjust the contentSize of the textview and the corresponding size of the textContainer, one additional method of changing the text wrap position (when using Auto Layout) is to make the trailing space to the SuperView into a negative value. This will allow one to push the word wrapping feature outward to the right. Not finished with the research just yet, but this tip should help anyone seeking to better control the UITextView word wrapping behavior.

Will post code once I'm complete but for now adjusting the trailing constraint of a UITextView will move the rightmost position of the word/character wrap.